# Same caption space

Tags: spacing, captions, minted

I want to have the same vertical spacing between figures/listings and their captions. Currently, the space between figure and caption is shorter than that between listing and caption. What should I do?

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{llncs}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[small,bf,up]{caption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] \includegraphics{test.png}
\caption{Test figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{listing}[!h]
\begin{inputminted}[linenos=true,frame=none]{java}{java/Test.java}\end{inputminted}
\caption{Test code}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Ok i could define a own command like:

```
\newcommand*{\CODE}[2]{
\begin{listing}[!h]
\begin{inputminted}[linenos=true,frame=none]{java}{java/#1.java}\end{inputminted}
\caption{#2}
\vspace{-1cm}
\end{listing}
}
```

but i how could i figure out which space i need in the vspace command?

Comment: I guess `\centering` is to blame here

Comment: No difference if i remove the centering

Comment: Please provide a MWE, not just fragments of code

Comment: Do you need more infos?

Comment: Well, no, but I have no time right now. And I doubt that Springer will let you change the distance of captions

Comment: @Andreas Is putting the code inside the `figure` environment and using its caption an option?

Comment: But then the number's are wrong

Comment: Nobody a better solution?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Have you tried using `\captionof` from caption (you could then use figure and label it otherwise)?